# Default lib jars folder for Apache Toree kernel

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, apache-toree

Say I want a default relative `lib` folder in jupyter notebook project directory where I can download custom jars so that I can import later without `%addjar` magic.

I was under [impression](https://toree.incubator.apache.org/docs/current/user/installation/) I can do something like:

```
"__TOREE_OPTS__": "--jar-dir=./lib/"
```

in `~/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/apache_toree_scala/kernel.json`,
but this doesn't work.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following `kernel.json` "just works":

```
# ~/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/apache_toree_scala/kernel.json
{
  "argv": [
    "/home/sergey/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/apache_toree_scala/bin/run.sh",
    "--profile",
    "{connection_file}"
  ],
  "env": {
    "DEFAULT_INTERPRETER": "Scala",
    "__TOREE_SPARK_OPTS__": "--jars=./lib/*.jar",
    "__TOREE_OPTS__": "",
    "SPARK_HOME": "/home/sergey/spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3"  
  },
  "display_name": "Apache Toree - Scala",
  "language": "scala",
  "interrupt_mode": "signal",
  "metadata": {}
}
```

Comment: Hopefully my answer helped

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the `kernel.json` file by adding the `--jars ./lib/*.jar` option under `env` section, pointing to the JAR files relative to the project directory

Comment: No, doesn't work

Comment: Though your answer was helpful in providing the right direction